# Documentation not generated in Xamarin bindings.xml

Tags: c#, android, xml, xamarin, documentation

I am trying to generate documentation for the android library in Xamarin in C#.
I have android library written in Kotlin and generated javadoc. The javaadoc is generated using dokka - Documentation engine for Kotlin(https://github.com/Kotlin/dokka)

I have generated Java bindings in Xamarin for my android library.
And I added javadoc in Java bindings project in Visual Studio. Set index.html in javadoc to JavaDocIndex in Java bindings project.
I also have also set  to true in the bindings project.

After building bindings project, .xml is generated in the bin\Debug folder.

In the xml, documentation for some of the apis is missing and displays 'To be added' in the tags of xml file.
In java doc, I am able to view the description of all apis. But, not in the generated xml file.

Eg:
Init() does not have description for the summary and parameters and instead displays 'To be added'.
In the .xml

```
<member name="M:Com.Sdk.Init(Android.Content.Context,System.String,Com.Sdk.Util.DSMode)">
            <param name="context">To be added.</param>
            <param name="paramA">To be added.</param>
            <param name="mode">To be added.</param>
            <summary>To be added.</summary>
            <returns>To be added.</returns>
            <remarks>To be added.</remarks>
</member>
```

During the build of bindings project, it displays the following log:

```
IMPORTJAVADOC : warning JavadocToMDoc0004: Could not find JavaDoc for member 'init(android.content.Context, java.lang.String, com.sdk.util.DSMode)' - managed member is 'Test Com.Sdk.Test::Init(Android.Content.Context,System.String,Com.Sdk.Util.DSMode)' [sdkbinding.csproj]
```

Can you let me know how to generate documentation for all the apis in the binding xml, which includes description of the apis.

Comment: You are missing a reference in your project or a using statement at top of module.  When you have System.Net.Socket it is a namespace.  You have 3 Libraries System, Net, and Socket.  Then in socket your have classes like TCPClient.  So in your case you need a using statements for  Android.Content.  System, and Com.Sdk.Util.  The last may be c++ code that you have to call using DLLImport if it is not a managed method.

Comment: As I mentioned in the post, java bindings are generated from existing kotlin based android library. I cannot use 'using Android.Content' etc because the android library is written in Kotlin. When java bindings are generated, it converts kotlin/java code to c# code and uses Xamarin Mono android framework for converting android apis to xamarin android apis. The java bindings work great when running with xamarin test application. The issue here is generating documentation in bindings project.xml.

Comment: The using statements at the top of the c# module in kotlin must be put in the M:Com.Sdk.Init statement.  So the missing reference instead of being added as a using statement goes in the Init.

Comment: Naveen did you try what @jdweng suggests and did it work?

Comment: @jdweng can you provide with an example. How to put using statements in M:Com.Sdk.Init statement

Comment: Did you try latest patches?